# How to return the value of javascript in cs file

Tags: javascript

I am having a usercontrol .cs file,from which i am making a javascript call like below.I have to read the value returned from javascript in my usercontrol.cs file

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, GetType(), "test", "javascript:GetCompanyName()", true);
```

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

store this value in a `HiddenFiled` then read it in code behind using

`HiddenField1.value`